# How can I find membership totals on a month by month basis eg. total members end of Jan, Feb ect so i can then analyse the increase month by month?

Tags: groups, smartgroups, civicrm-home

I have found how to get Civi to show me how many new members of each type joined per month. However I need the total of all members at the end of January Feb etc so I can see if there is an increase in members and of which type.

Comment: worth mentioning what cms you are using as some reports are easier to build using CMS tools, eg Views for Drupal

Comment: Given that membership is a core aspect of functionality, the default reporting tools are pretty woeful when it comes to membership. Trying to find out, for example, who was a member on a given date in the past is something that everyone with a membership responsibility will need to know, but it feels really difficult to get hold of.

Answer (score 1):

I would firstly suggest checking out the [Membership Churn extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/membership-churn-reports)

Comment: Pete thanks for that suggestion, and it looks like just the thing that Adam is looking for. I was looking for a similar report and way to calc the 'point in time' monthly membership counts a few years ago now, and glad that you put us on to this.  I've also installed it and am checking it out on a demo site,  so I have to add some more dummy membership data to see it working better in action....